# if i have layer 1, 2 and 3, how do i user layer 1 to mask out only layer two using layer mask

Tags: render-layers, masking, layers

I need to be able to animate and rotate my mask, and therefore i want to use the layermask, however it should only mask out the layer right under it.

So i want layer 1 to mask out layer 2, and not touch layer 3.